# Scope inside class of C++

Tags: c++

```
class cl { 
    public:
        cl(int i) { val=i; }
        int val;
        int double_val() { return val+val; }
};
```

Variable val is declared after the constructor, which assigns it. But still this code works. Isn't 'val' out of scope for constructor?

Comment: @Downvoter, what is the reason for the downvote? This question contains [mcve], in addition to clear, and specific question. If the reason for the downvote was "no research", you could have suggested a duplicate.

Answer (score 4):

The full definition of the class is available to its members. So `val` is actually declared before the constructor's implementation.